# VB.net connect Disconnect USB Internet Modem

Tags: vb.net, usb, internet-connection

[image: Usb Internet Modem Connection]

Hi i am trying to connect / disconnect USB internet modem programmatically through vb.net .  i already somehow manage to get code for connect / disconnect modem internet connection. but its not working for mobile broadband connection. (USB Internet Modem )

Answer (score 0):

To Connect:-
Shell("rasdial connectionname [username [password | *]] [/domain:domain]")
To Disconnect:-
Shell("rasdial /disconnect")

Comment: Try to add more description.